# How to set QFrame color in an eventFilter?

Tags: pyqt5, qframe, eventfilter

I have a simple QWidget that contains a frame and two labels. I want to use eventFilter to change QFrame background color on label hover. Can someone please check the below code and tell me why I can't change the QFrame background and if it is the correct way for doing it?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QPushButton, QApplication, QComboBox, QFrame, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.setObjectName("frame")
        self.frame_lay = QHBoxLayout()

        self.one_label = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.one_label.setText("one")
        self.one_label.setObjectName("one")

        self.two_label = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.two_label.setText("two")
        self.two_label.setObjectName("two")

        self.one_label.installEventFilter(self)
        self.two_label.installEventFilter(self)

        self.frame_lay.addWidget(self.one_label)
        self.frame_lay.addWidget(self.two_label)

        self.frame.setStyleSheet("""QFrame{background-color: red;}""")

        self.frame.setLayout(self.frame_lay)
        self.frame_lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            if type(obj) == QLabel:
                if obj.objectName() in ["one", "two"]:
                    print(obj.objectName())    
                    self.frame.setStyleSheet("""QFrame#frame{background-color: blue;}""")
        return super(QWidget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Should the installEventFilter be applied to QWidget or QFrame? The labels are contained within the QFrame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `frame` object name for the "MainWindow", but in the event filter you used the object name for a QFrame class.

Just set the object name for the frame instead:

```
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
```

Note that QLabel inherits from QFrame, so, using `QFrame{background-color: red;}` technically applies the background for both the parent frame *and* any child label.
In case you want to be more specific, you either use the object name as you did in the event filter, or use the `.ClassName` selector, which applies the sheet only to the class and not its subclasses (note the full stop character before `QFrame`):

```
    self.frame.setStyleSheet(""".QFrame{background-color: red;}""")
```